# Ember Controller when rendering into existing template

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am working through the Ember tutorial and it's working well, but I can't quite figure out one aspect of it.

[Show Only Completed Todos](http://emberjs.com/guides/getting-started/show-only-complete-todos/)

```
Todos.Router.map(function () {
  this.resource('todos', { path: '/' }, function () {  // Index route
    // additional child routes
    this.route('active');       // Implicit this.route("active", { path: "/active" });
    this.route('completed');    // Implicit this.route("completed", { path: "/completed" });
  });
});

...

Todos.TodosCompletedRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return this.store.filter('todo', function(todo) {
      return todo.get('isCompleted');
    });
  },
  renderTemplate: function(controller) {
    this.render('todos/index', {controller: controller});
  }
});
```

It makes sense to me that we are reusing an existing template and simply changing the assigned model, in this case, restricting it to just the list of completed todos.

What I don't understand is the `{controller: controller}` argument to render.

According to the Ember inspector in Chrome, with or without the `{controller: controller}` argument the controller is `TodosCompletedController`.

If the `{controller: controller}` argument is present then going to the application route (In my case `file:///Users/dpwrussell/Checkout/web/ember/TodoMVC/index.html#/` and then clicking on Completed causes the correct response, displaying just the completed todos.

Without the `{controller: controller}` argument, clicking on the Completed link displays the full list of todos, not just the completed ones.

Finally, if going direct to the url `file:///Users/dpwrussell/Checkout/web/ember/TodoMVC/index.html#/completed` then the correct list of only completed todos is displayed regardless of the fact that `{controller: controller}` is missing, but if you go to All, then Completed again using the links, it will stop working again.

[jsbin displaying the problem](http://jsbin.com/OzUvuPu/24/)

[jsbin showing how it works if you go directly to completed url](http://jsbin.com/OzUvuPu/24/#/completed)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can take a look at Route's [render](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_render) and [renderTemplate](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Route.html#method_renderTemplate) methods to get a better understanding. If the controller had not been specified in `this.render('todos/index', {controller: controller})` then Ember would create and use TodosCompletedController since the route is TodosCompletedRoute. The parameter 'controller' is not the TodosController, it is the generated TodosCompletedController. Everything should work correctly even if the controller is not passed while calling `render`. Here's [JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/OzUvuPu/22#/completed).

Comment: Thanks, but I have already read those and still don't quite get it. I know that it would use `TodosCompletedController` if the controller was not specified, my question is about how the correct controller `TodosController` ends up being used. I don't see how the passed in `controller` knows to be this.

Comment: I'm afraid that is definitely not the case and the reason I started wondering about this in the first place. It seemed to me that the passed in controller must be `TodosCompletedController` not `TodosController`. `TodosCompletedController` would be the default and what should appear if there is no `{controller: controller}`. Removing `{controller: controller}` causes the completed and active functionality to not update the list of todos shown. However, if the page is refreshed while on the url for active/completed then they appear correctly.

Comment: I have added the jsbin. You can check it out.

Comment: Your jsbin demonstrates the behaviour I just described. If you click on 'active' (`{controller: controller}` still in place) then it correctly shows just the uncompleted items, but if you click on completed then it shows all 3 items, not just the 1 completed one.

Comment: Something is strange about jsbin, it works correctly after refresh. I have updated the link. You can still follow from console or Ember inspector and see that controller parameter is TodosCompletedController that is generated by Ember.

Comment: I accept that TodosCompletedController is being used, but when `{controller: controller}` is removed the behaviour is definitely not correct as my local non-jsbin demonstrates the problem. As I describe earlier, when going directly to a completed url (or just refresh), the problem does not manifest so thus your new jsbin does not demonstrate the problem. When going direct to the completed url it only manifests again after clicking on 'All' which you can't do in the jsbin. The behaviour I describe is exactly as in your original jsbin.